# How to bind 2 textfields and at least 1 out of 3 checkboxes to a button

Tags: java, javafx, binding

Right now I have this button which I want to enable once 2 textfields have been filled out and at least 1 out of 3 checkboxes are checked. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work the way it's suppose to. I would greatly appreciate any of your inputs. Thank you in advance.

```
button.disableProperty().bind(
   Bindings.isEmpty(textField1.textProperty())
   .or(Bindings.isEmpty(textField2.textProperty()))
   .or(checkBox1.selectedProperty())
   .or(checkBox2.selectedProperty())
   .or(checkBox3.selectedProperty())
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of chaining `or`, `and` and `not` to create an expression for one simple reason. The actual expression isn't easy to read. `Bindings.createBooleanBinding` results in code that is much easier to read:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    () -> {
        if (textField1.getText().isEmpty() || textField2.getText().isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return !(checkBox1.isSelected() || checkBox2.isSelected() || checkBox3.isSelected());
    },
    textField1.textProperty(), textField1.textProperty(), checkBox1.selectedProperty(), checkBox2.selectedProperty(), checkBox3.selectedProperty()
));
```

If you insist on chainging `and`, `or` and `not`, you should create the following expression:

```
(e1 || e2 || !(s1 || s2 || s3))
```

where `e1` and `e2` stand for empty text fields and `s1`, `s2`, `s3` for selected checkboxes

```
button.disableProperty().bind(
    textField1.textProperty().isEmpty()
           .or(textField2.textProperty().isEmpty())
           .or(
               checkBox1.selectedProperty()
                        .or(checkBox2.selectedProperty())
                        .or(checkBox3.selectedProperty()).not())
);
```

Comment: True. It does look more readable using "Bindings.createBooleanBinding" compared to chaining it with "or, and, not". I haven't seen the difference before with the way I have been doing it but your explanation between the two approaches makes it clearer now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually tried the solution listed below. It seems to work in that it needs to fill out 2 textfields and check at least 1 out of 3 checkboxes.

```
button.disableProperty().bind(
   Bindings.isEmpty(textField1.textProperty())
   .and(Bindings.isEmpty(textField2.textProperty()))
   .or(checkBox1.selectedProperty().not())
   .and(checkBox2.selectedProperty().not())
   .and(checkBox3.selectedProperty().not())
);
```

Comment: Let `e1` and `e2` denote the empty state of the `TextField`s and `s1`, `s2`, `s3` be the selection state of the `CheckBox`es. The binding you create here is `((e1 && e2) || !s1) && (!s2) && (!s3)`, i.e. as long as both text fields are empty and the last 2 checkboxes are unselected, the state of the first checkbox does not matter. Also if at least one of the textfields and checkbox 1 is selected, the button is enabled.